# ActiveRecord WHERE NOT EXISTS

Tags: activerecord

Is there a way to use EXISTS with ActiveRecord besides find_by_sql?

I'd like a nice way to find all records without an association in a One-to-Many relationship.

```
SELECT DISTINCT store_type FROM stores
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM cities_stores
                    WHERE cities_stores.store_type = stores.store_type)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Store.all(:select => "DISTINCT store_type",
          :conditions => "NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM cities_stores WHERE cities_stores.store_type = stores.store_type)")
```

ActiveRecord will execute the same query as what you entered above. The returned Store instances will have a single store_type attribute.

Comment: It would be nice if there were a way to write the inner query using standard ActiveRecord methods, rather than raw SQL. Is that possible?

Comment: @AndrewCone did you try using `join`? See official document http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#using-array-hash-of-named-associations